# Select an element who as a last child with property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<bus>
    <port>
        <req>
            <item>
            [...]
            </item> 
        </req>
        [...]
        <req>
            <item>
            [...]
            </item> 
        </req>
    </port>
    [...]
    <port>
        <req>
            <item>
            [...]
            </item> 
        </req>
        [...]
        <req>
            <item>
            [...]
            </item> 
        </req>
    </port>
</bus>
<bus>
[...] (same as before)
</bus>
```

I have this structure; all the structures repeats themselves. I need to select the last port element of a bus which has a last child with property "mode"=="read".

It can exist a bus which has a last port element with a last child with property different from "read", so I need to choose the right port element.

I tried lots of tries, last one is this, but does not works:

```
var modbusportSelected = Elements("bus").Elements("port")
.Where( x => x.Elements("req")
.Any(y => y.Attribute("mode").Value.Contains("read")))
.Last();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; also, I'm totally new with LINQ to XML and I cannot find a single webpage where to get the exact meaning of "Any" and if there are other operators, and if so, what they are.

Comment: Any just returns a bool, the conditions are set from within the any method. In your case you are saying are there any mode attributes that have the value containing read.

Comment: thanks! Do you also know where can i find some decent documentation about Any and other operators?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be significant that your XML snippet needs a top level element. If you wrap what you have above in an outer tag, then your code appears to work provided you trap null references from any `port` elements which don't have a `mode` attribute. eg.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string xml = @"<topLevel><bus>
    <port isCorrectNode='no'>
        <req>
            <item>
            </item> 
        </req>
        <req mode='read'>
            <item>
            </item> 
        </req>
    </port>
    <port isCorrectNode='yes'>
        <req mode='read'>
            <item>
            </item> 
        </req>
        <req>
            <item>
            </item> 
        </req>
    </port>
</bus>
<bus>
</bus>
</topLevel>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

            var found = root.Elements("bus").Elements("port")
                .Where(x => x.Elements("req").Any(y => y.Attribute("mode") != null && y.Attribute("mode").Value.Contains("read")))
                .Last();

            var isThisTheCorrectNode = found.Attribute("isCorrectNode").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(isThisTheCorrectNode);
        }
    }
}
```

will write `yes`

Edit: I've noticed your code looks for the last `port` which has *any* child `req` whose mode is 'read'. but your question asked for the *last* such `req`. In that case:

```
var wanted = root.Elements("bus").Elements("port")
    .Where(x => x.Elements("req").Any() && // make sure there is a req element
x.Elements("req").Last().Attribute("mode") != null && // and it has the attribute  
x.Elements("req").Last().Attribute("mode").Value.Contains("read")) // and it has the right value
    .Last();
```